# Assembly - Why there are changing values in a static analized code?

Tags: memory, reverse-engineering, static-analysis, disassembly

I would like to extend a program's code and I want to access a specific data there. My issue is that the address of that specific data keeps changing every system restart. For example the data currently defined like this `.data:00B374F1 byte_B374F1` next time after system restart it is going to be different so my new code won't work then.

I understand that the address is changing because of some pre memory allocation, but isn't that only related to dynamic analization? I would really appreciate if someone could help me out, I am new at assembly.

Comment: Read about ASLR. This is probably intentional.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. I've never heard it before. I am sure that is the case now.